# Guarantee that a table never stores the distance from Y to X if distance X to Y already exists

Tags: postgresql, ddl

Take a look at the condition below, what does it really mean?  Both 'fromCity' and 'toCity' are strings so does it make any sense to compare those two?

The goal is to find a solution that guarantees that the table never stores the distance from Y to X if it already has the distance from X to Y.

```
CREATE TABLE Distances (
fromCity TEXT,
toCity TEXT,
distance INT,
CONSTRAINT only_one_direction CHECK (fromCity < toCity)
) ;
```

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Store only Berlin -> Paris, do not allow Paris -> Berlin.

Comment: @jarlh: that check constraint won't ensure that. You need a unique constraint on `(fromcity, tocity)` as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I know it's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: @jarlh I'm still wondering how you can compare two strings like that? How will the compiler know which one is the greatest if we store 'Berlin' in 'fromcity' and 'Paris' in 'toCity'?

Answer (score 3):

You need a unique constraint (or index) to ensure that. The check constraint alone will not prevent from adding the same combination again (it also imposes some restriction on the client to sort the two names before inserting).

A better approach is a unique index that makes sure that only one combination can be stored:

```
CREATE TABLE distances 
(
  fromcity TEXT,
  tocity TEXT,
  distance INT,
);
create unique index on distances ( least(fromcity,tocity), greatest(fromcity,tocity) );
```

The expression index will always store the cities in the same order, thus making sure the combination is unique.

Comment: Nice! Once again, PostgreSQL does it the right way.